# WCF 5.0 and Firebird .NET Provider: $expand broken

Tags: wcf-data-services, firebird

The problem described in the link below (WCF 5.0 & DevArt provider) seems to be also true for the Firebird .NET Provider:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/e74ea4d1-a262-4326-8529-c146a3acfb6d

However I've tried the 5.1.0-pre release and still get the ArumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value.

Besides of that the behaviour is exactly the same as described. It did work in the WCF 5.0 CTP, though.

Can anyone confirm that this is a Bug in WCF 5.0 RC or the Firebird .NET Provider? Is there a workaround, or do I have to downgrade to the CTP?

This is the call stack:

```
Microsoft.Data.Services.dll!System.Data.Services.WebUtil.CheckArgumentNull<string>(string alue, string parameterName) + 0x34 bytes  
Microsoft.Data.Services.dll!System.Data.Services.Internal.ExpandedWrapper<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.ServerGroup>.ReferenceDescription.set(string value) + 0x33 bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator<System.Data.Services.Internal.ExpandedWrapper<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.ServerGroup,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.Server>>>.ReadNextElement(System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper shaper) + 0x41 bytes   
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper<System.Data.Services.Internal.ExpandedWrapper<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.ServerGroup,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.Server>>>.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext() + 0xec bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper<System.Data.Services.Internal.ExpandedWrapper<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.ServerGroup,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.Server>>>.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement() + 0x11 bytes    
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper<System.Data.Services.Internal.ExpandedWrapper<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.ServerGroup,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.Server>>>.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext() + 0x3a bytes    
Microsoft.Data.Services.dll!System.Data.Services.Providers.BasicExpandProvider.ExpandedEnumerator<System.Data.Services.Internal.ExpandedWrapper<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.ServerGroup,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.Server>>>.MoveNext() + 0x23 bytes    
Microsoft.Data.Services.dll!System.Data.Services.DataService<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.SetupContext>.SerializeResponseBody(System.Data.Services.RequestDescription description, System.Data.Services.IDataService dataService, Microsoft.Data.OData.IODataResponseMessage responseMessage) + 0x246 bytes    
Microsoft.Data.Services.dll!System.Data.Services.DataService<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.SetupContext>.HandleNonBatchRequest(System.Data.Services.RequestDescription description) + 0x1d8 bytes   
Microsoft.Data.Services.dll!System.Data.Services.DataService<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.SetupContext>.HandleRequest() + 0x13e bytes  
Microsoft.Data.Services.dll!System.Data.Services.DataService<Mdv.AppGuard.Central.Data.SetupContext>.ProcessRequestForMessage(System.IO.Stream messageBody) + 0xe3 bytes    
[Lightweight Function]  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs) + 0x8c7 bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x243 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x9f bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0xa2 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0xd9 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x102 bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x99 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x96 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x8e4 bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc) + 0x63 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(bool isOperationContextSet) + 0x122 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Dispatch(ref System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc rpc, bool isOperationContextSet) + 0x49 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext request, bool cleanThread, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext currentOperationContext) + 0x5d4 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext request, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext currentOperationContext) + 0x226 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x77 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x6a bytes   
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x32 bytes  
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(bool completedSynchronously) + 0xfd bytes  
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.InputQueue<System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext>.AsyncQueueReader.Set(System.Runtime.InputQueue<System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext>.Item item) + 0x44 bytes 
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.InputQueue<System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext>.EnqueueAndDispatch(System.Runtime.InputQueue<System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext>.Item item, bool canDispatchOnThisThread) + 0x1aa bytes    
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.InputQueue<System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext>.EnqueueAndDispatch(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext item, System.Action dequeuedCallback, bool canDispatchOnThisThread) + 0x5e bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext>.EnqueueAndDispatch(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext item, System.Action dequeuedCallback, bool canDispatchOnThisThread) + 0x46 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IReplyChannel,System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannel,System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext>.Enqueue(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext item, System.Action dequeuedCallback, bool canDispatchOnThisThread) + 0x68 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IReplyChannel,System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannel,System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext>.Enqueue(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext item, System.Action dequeuedCallback) + 0x2b bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext context, System.Action callback) + 0x352 bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContextCore(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x400 bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnGetContext(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x3d bytes   
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll!System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult result) + 0x32 bytes  
System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(System.IntPtr userToken) + 0x6c bytes    
System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(object result, System.IntPtr userToken) + 0xbb bytes  
System.dll!System.Net.ListenerAsyncResult.WaitCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped) + 0x1f5 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) + 0x74 bytes
```

Comment: Could you please post the callstack of the exception? It will help us determine if it really is the exact same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've added the call stack to the question above.

Comment: Are you sure that this is running the 5.1.0-rc build? Note that in order for the NuGet package to be applied you have to remove the 5.0 release from the GAC (if you installed it using the MSI and not NuGet).

Comment: No, it should be 5.0. I've tried 5.1.0, but since that didn't work either, I've rolled back to 5.0. But I didn't remove 5.0 from the GAC, maybe that 5.1 will than fix my issue. I will try that again and come back - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.1.0-rc build fixes also the problem for the Firebird provider. As Vitek Karas mentioned I forgot to remove the 5.0 RTM from the GAC. Therefore I've never really tried 5.1.0-rc.